# vector quality of svg and pdf

Tags: pdf, svg

I'm converting pdf files to svg as it is easier to use svg files on webpages.
I first thought the quality of svg must be similar to pdf, as they are both vector graphics.

However, now I look a little better on it, it seems that pdf is a bit superior:

[image: Comparison of pdf and svg]
(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/58922976/Photos/1.png)

I wonder if I could change this in some way.

- Is this because pdf vectors are just better quality ?
- Or is this because chrome renders svg in lower quality than adobe reader renders pdf ?
- Is this a setting in the svg file that I could change ?

Here is the pdf file: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/58922976/syllabusLinAlg2012.59.pdf
And here is the svg file: 
[image: SVG file]
(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/58922976/syllabusLinAlg2012.59.svg)

I've made this svg file in illustrator, and only chrome is able to use the embedded [svg fonts](http://caniuse.com/svg-fonts). So firefox and internet explorer won't give the expected result.

Comment: @Karan I changed it.

Comment: That makes sense. Anyway, you still haven't told us what you used to convert PDF to SVG, and whether you've tried any alternatives?

Comment: I embedded the images in the post...I hope that makes it better